# Excel - Extract a List Based on a Condition

Tags: arrays, excel, list, indexing, match

I am having some trouble extracting a unique list from an Excel table based on a condition.

Basically, the table looks like this (Table is in A1:B11):

```
Name     Count
Person1  10
Person2  2
Person3  3
Person4  1
Person5  1
Person6  18
Person7  1
Person8  5
Person9  7
Person10 2
```

I want to be able to extract the people out of this table that have Counts > 1 and have a new table that looks like this:

```
Name     Count
Person1  10
Person2  2
Person3  3
Person6  18
Person8  5
Person9  7
Person10 2
```

I have been trying to use index and match, but it has not been working out exactly the way I want.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: What would be the way you want to achieve it? There are plenty of ways such as filter/selection and copy/paste. There is VBA.. What are your restrictions?

Comment: I just want to produce the list using INDEX and MATCH.  I feel like I'm close, but it's not working.

   { =INDEX(Table4[Person],MATCH(">1",Table4[Count],0))}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have a `Sheet1` table on `A1:B11` like this:

```
Name     Count
Person1  10
Person2  2
Person3  3
Person4  1
Person5  1
Person6  18
Person7  1
Person8  5
Person9  7
Person10 2
```

1) Select cell `D1` (as an example) and type:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$B;SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B:$B>1;ROW(Sheet1!$B:$B));ROW(1:1));1;1);"")`
now press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to apply the `{`...`}` around the formula and drag `D1` down for a few rows (it will show all the `A` Names that match your formula).

2) Select cell `E1` (as an example) and type:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$B;SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B:$B>1;ROW(Sheet1!$B:$B));ROW(1:1));2;1);"")`
now press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to apply the `{`...`}` around the formula again and drag `E1` down for a few rows (it will show all the `B` Count that match your formula).

You'll get something like this as a result:

```
Name        Count   Name        Count
Person1     10      Person1     10
Person2     2       Person2     2
Person3     3       Person3     3
Person4     1       Person6     18
Person5     1       Person8     5
Person6     18      Person9     7
Person7     1       Person10    2
Person8     5           
Person9     7           
Person10    2
```